# Laravel local.ERROR: array_merge(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array, string given

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-6, pusher

I have been trying to set up a basic chatroom and am at the final stages but have been trying to deal with this error for days since I am new to Laravel. I am using Laravel 6. What I am trying to do is push a message using pusher so the chatroom gets updated in real-time, however when I push the message I get a  POST 500 (Internal Server Error)

The full error states from the log file:

> local.ERROR: array_merge(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array,
> string given {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code:
> 0): array_merge(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array, string given

I have tried everything I can think of, I have tried to cast the column user_id as an array using json, I have tried to change the column name. Please find down below my migration table and the Message model:

```
class Message extends Model
{
@var array

protected $fillable = ['message'];
protected $table= 'messages';

protected $hidden = ['user_id'];

/**
 * A message belong to a user
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
}
```

Here is the table:

```
 Schema::create('messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->text('message');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Many thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: There's no array_merge() in the code you posted, where is it being called?

Comment: I believe here: \\vendor\\pusher\\pusher-php-server\\src\\Pusher.php(518): array_merge(Array, '131299.23450634')

Comment: Post the message you're pushing.

Comment: {"id":10,"message":"kkj","created_at":"2021-03-04 03:17:52","updated_at":"2021-03-04 03:17:52","user":{"id":1,"name":"Ryan Thompson","email":"ryanthompson139@gmail.com","email_verified_at":"2021-03-04 01:47:50","created_at":"2021-03-04 01:47:50","updated_at":"2021-03-04 01:47:50"}}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved in v8.29.0 of Laravel